# Formatting in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have this:

```
artists = search_object.map{|x| x["artistName"]}.uniq
=> ["Metallica", "Madonna", "Lady Gaga"]
```

I need it in this format json:

```
{"artists":[{"name":"Metallica"},{"name":"Madonna"},{"name":"Lady Gaga"}]}
```

I tried this:

```
>>     @api = {}
=> {}
>>          @api[:artists] = artists
=> ["Metallica", "Madonna", "Lady Gaga"]
>> @api
=> {:artists=>["Metallica", "Madonna", "Lady Gaga"]}
```

I need it in an api call like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @api}
end
```

But whats returned is not proper json.

How do I get it in this format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple `Enumerable#map` should do:

```
artists = ["Metallica", "Madonna", "Lady Gaga"]
@api = {:artists => artists.map { |artist| {:name => artist} }}
#=> {:artists=>[{:name=>"Metallica"}, {:name=>"Madonna"}, {:name=>"Lady Gaga"}]}
```

Note that you can use symbol as hash keys (it's more idiomatic) because they are converted to JSON as normal strings.